# Deformation energy in elastic collisions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, energy-conservation, collision

A ball moving translationally collides elastically with another stationary ball of the same mass. At the moment of impact, the angle between the straight line passing through the centres of the balls and the initial motion of the striking ball is equal to θ. Assuming the balls to be smooth, the fraction of the kinetic energy of the striking ball that is turned into potential energy at the moment of maximum deformation is 3/n cos^2θ. Find 'n'

[image: Figure:]

I know the expression for loss in kinetic energy but have no idea whether it is applicable or not.

P.S: This isn't a homework question. I got my exams coming up and this is one I just came across.

Comment: The tag is homework-and-EXERCISES. The same policy applies to all homework-like exercises. There's no practical way in which we can verify if the problem has actually been set as homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the expression for loss in kinetic energy but have no idea
>   whether it is applicable or not.

I couldn't have understood what you mean by the term *the expression for loss in kinetic energy*, so I couldn't use your expression.

Anyway, the process would be as follows:

1. By using center of mass coordinate, you can simplify the problem.
2. Then you can divide the kinetic energy of the whole system into two parts: a) parallel to the line passing through the centres of the balls, and b) perpendicular to it.
3. At the moment of the maximum deformation, the a) would be zero and this change would be the quantity you want to evaluate.